# AspectJ warning 'Xlint:adviceDidNotMatch' for 'target()' pointcut against static method

Tags: java, aspectj

I am new to AspectJ and still learning hot to write code.
I am trying to make a pointcut and advice for nextYear() method, but i keep getting "Warning:(39, 0) ajc: advice defined in ChristkindAspect has not been applied [Xlint:adviceDidNotMatch]". I understand that it is probably because an Object is not being directly created, and that i cannot use target(christkind`enter code here`), but i cannot find a solution. Can anybody help? Thank you in advance!

```
pointcut nextYear(Christkind christkind, Population population):
  call(* *Christkind.nextYear(Population))&& args(population) && 
  target(christkind);


before(Christkind christkind,Population population): nextYear(christkind,population) {
    System.out.println("New Year");
    populationSize(population);
    numbOfWIshes(population);
    //wishStrength(population); }
```

In main method i have:

```
Christkind.nextYear(population);
```

[image]

Comment: Funny, in a few days the second question about AspectJ and populations. Do you happen to know the guy who asked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53793975/1082681)? Anyway, welcome to SO and a  general hint for asking questions: Please try to provide an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). In the context of AspectJ this means that if you want to debug AOP-related code, we need both aspect and application code because they get woven into each other. Aspect code alone is not enough. Also (error) logs during compilation or execution are often helpful.

Comment: Besides, please always provide code in text format and not as screenshot only. I cannot copy code from your screenshot and run it.

Comment: I also renamed your question from "AspectJ pointcut" to something more specific.

Answer (score 0):

Warning `Xlint:adviceDidNotMatch` means that no code in the scope of the aspect weaver or compiler was found matched by the pointcut in your aspect. Thus, the advice in question was not applied to (i.e. woven into) your target application code.

In your screenshot I see that your target method is static, also the way your main method calls it implies that:

```java
Christkind.nextYear(population);
```

The `target()` pointcut designator checks if the target object is an instance of whatever you specify. But for a static method there is no instance, thus the name static method, not instance method. Consequently, your pointcut will not match. So either you make your method non-static (if you want to do something with the target instance object) or you need to use another pointcut designator such as `within(Christkind)` instead. It seems as though you are not even using the supposed `Christkind` instance in your advice code, only the `Population` instance. Thus, just get rid of the `target()` part or replace it by `within()`.

Feel free to ask related(!) follow-up questions.

Comment: Thank you for your anwser and the helpful tipps! I tryed within() but it is still not working. If i leave the parameters(Christkind christkind,Population population) and use within(Christkind) then i get a formal unbound in pointcut error. If i only use Population as as parameter then I get a warning again that advice is not being applied.

Comment: Of course you need to remove the Christkind parameter. If you want more help, please update your question with a full [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (classes, package names, aspects, configuration) or publish one on GitHub, then notify me. I cannot help you debug something I do not see.

Answer (score 0):

```
before(): execution(* Packages.*.*(..))
    {
         //packages is com
        System.out.println(" TEST");    

    }
```

Try this to find your correct advice

Comment: Please add some explanation how it solves the issue

Comment: replace |     nextYear(christkind,population)      | with |       execution(* Packages.*.*(..))     |.
Enter your own package in |   * Packages.*.*(..)   | then use this to find the correct advice for the [Xlint:adviceDidNotMatch] error